# Can not start android emulator - Hyper V detected but Hypervisor platform is not available

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, hyper-v, hypervisor

I am running into an issue where I can't start the xamarin android emulator, it says:

```
Device error: WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pie_9_0_-_api_28'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=c23d7e88-c1e4-4283-bb2b-e2632b5c3c16'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
ERROR   | x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
CPU acceleration status: Hyper-V detected and Windows Hypervisor Platform is not available. Please either disable Hyper-V or upgrade to Windows 10 1803 or later. To disable Hyper-V, start a command prompt as Administrator, run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off', reboot. If u
More info on configuring VM acceleration on Windows:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows
General information on acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.
```

I *need* Hyper-V to be enabled for the emulator acceleration, otherwise if i disable it, the apps on the emulator run painfully slowly. The thing is I had hyper-v enabled before, and all of my emulators ran just fine with it, then suddenly I started getting this error. Both Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform are enabled in windows features. I also have HAXM accelerator installed for the android. I also tried running the following commands: bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto and dism /online /enable-feature /feature-name:Microsoft-Hyper-V -All; both commands resulted in "operation completed successfully". I also tried running "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator-check.exe" accel, and this is what I got:

```
accel:
0
Please disable Hyper-V before using the Android Emulator.  Start a command prompt as Administrator, run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off', reboot.WHPX (10.0.19042) is installed and usable.
accel
```

I am not sure what is going on, and why my emulators suddenly can not run with Hyper-V enabled. Has anyone faced this issue before? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very weird but still to this day I can't start the android emulator in VS2019. However, I found a workaround - I can start the android emulator in VS2017, so I start it there and run the app from VS2019. Extremely weird, but if anyone is having that issue and needs a workaround urgently, that's what you can do.
I don't know if this is helpful at all, but as for today, that's the only solution I found.

(Also, consider switching to VS2022. Seems to work fine there as well)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall HAXM; it reads: `WHPX (10.0.19042) is installed and usable.`

This is the "Windows Hypervisor Platform" ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried uninstalling HAXM, still getting the same thing :c